# How should I go about repairing this door casing?

Tags: bathroom, basement, mold, door-frame, rot

It's the door of the bathroom in the basement, which hasn't been used for at least one year. The relative humidity is 50%. I'm not sure how the rot happened, since it was before I moved in. The rotted part is as hard as the normal part of the door casing.

As I can find online, the typical way to repair is to either replace part of the jamb with new wood or to fill with epoxy after removing the rotted wood. However, my case seems not that severe, are the above still the right ways to go? If not, what should I do? Thank you.

Edit: The rotted part is as hard as the normal part of the door casing. I scrapped the loose paint, and also removed the tile in the second photo, and photos are added. I have tested with tissue paper and confirmed the door casing is dry. It's the bathroom in the basement, close to the exterior foundation wall. The shower door sweep is missing, I guess water came out from the gap when it was in use.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is the wood soft?  Can you push a nail in or is it just bad paint peeling?  If wood is soft, replacement is the best.

Comment: The rotted part is as hard as the upper half of the door casing.

Comment: Do you own or rent? If you're the owner, it would be worthwhile doing some serious investigation to see if there's a water leak (or signs of a former water leak) that's causing this, or if it's just failing paint.

Comment: It's not even been prepped yet to repair. Scrap lose paint. What are you left with?

Comment: The pics only show the "damaged" parts. What does the rest of it look like? If the wood is still hard, it may only need a simple scraping to get rid of the flaking paint and perhaps a skim of filler to deal with the imperfections of the cracking and such. This is, if it is a simple profile. If it is a more "curvy" or ornate profile that some is missing because of the cracking, will be a different matter

Comment: The rest of the door casing is okay. I scrapped the loose paint, and also removed the tile in the second photo, and photos are added. I have tested with tissue paper and confirmed the door casing is dry. It's the bathroom in the basement, close to the exterior foundation wall. The shower door sweep is missing, I guess water came out from the gap when it was in use.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like the same problem area as your first question. The wood destroying organisms are pretty thick there and the result of water infiltration just like the mildew on the tiles. If there were old water issues the mildew would be dried over time and be like dust rather than the deep dark black that shows in your pics. You need to correct the source of the infiltration or you will be fighting this and wasting time and money for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

From your second picture, it appears there is also a moisture issue behind the baseboard. To fix it right means finding and eliminating the source of this water, as well as replacing all of the unsound wood.

The key to the repair is to replace rotten wood with solid wood while removing the source of damage.

The easy (and more expensive) way to do that is probably to pull off and replace the entire piece of trim, assuming you can match the profile or use a new profile that you are satisfied with.

The cheap (and more labor intensive) way is to cut out and replace only the damaged wood.

Answer (score 0):

Do a test first to determine the damage.

Use a 2-3 inch long nail and push it in with hand close to the bottom, where it looks worse.

If it goes deeper the 1 inch without significant resistance than the framing wood is also damaged, which would mean you need a professional to fix it.

However if it passes the nail test, then it is only the door framing, which is decorative and has no structural impact.

**DIY method's**

The cheapest on would be to scrape the loose paint, and use **rotten wood filler** that will repair the rot. Prime and Paint.

More elaborate method would be the to replace the framing, which requires some skills.

Comment: The rotted part is as hard as the normal part of the door casing.

Comment: @bobby_yan so that is good news, surface rot only, use the `rotten wood filler` to repair that. Le me know if you find my answer and comments useful.

Comment: Is `rotten wood filler` different than `regular wood filler`?

Comment: @FreeMan google it to find out

Comment: Usually, we like answers that stand on their own and don't require "googling" to figure them out.

Comment: @FreeMan the answer is very instructive, it clearly points out the specific product to use. No need for me to justify it and compare to other products.

Comment: @FreeMan to answer your question `Is rotten wood filler different than regular wood filler`  Yes it is !